# Setting properties of textbox and formatting it in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using MVC 2.  I want to format the data that I display in my textbox when I edit a record.

I display my textbox like this:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AnnualIncome, new { @class = "textbox", maxlength = "50", size = "15" })%>
```

How would I format this?  I tried adding the String.Format from below but it does not work:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AnnualIncome, String.Format("{0:F}", Model.AnnualIncome)) %>
```

AnnualIncome is of type Nullable decimal.

EDIT:

I am putting in a thousands separator to give me a value like 1,000,000 just to see the result.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:0,0}")]
public Nullable<decimal> AnnualIncome { get; set; }
```

Here is my HTML for the above:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AnnualIncome, new { @class = "textbox", maxlength = "50", size = "15" })%>
```

This still displays 1000000.00.  I am trying to get it to display 1000000 in the textbox when the view is populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `DisplayFormatAttribute.DataFormatString` attribute on the property:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString = "{0:F}")]
public float AnnualIncome { get; set; };
```

Then you just do:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.AnnualIncome) %>
```

To style the inputs, you can do:

```
input.editor-field {
    color: #781351;
}
```

...or whatever you prefer.

Comment: Html.EditorFor works fine, but it doesn't use the styling that I provide.  Why does EditorFor work and not TextBoxFor?

Comment: `EditorFor` uses the model metadata. `TextBoxFor` doesn't. I should have suggested `EditorFor`. What styling are you trying to preserve.

Comment: The textbox that the EditorFor displays looks like a plain HTML input control.  It uses some sort of default styling.  I don't use that styling, I have my own style that I apply to my textboxes.  How do I apply my style to the input textbox that the EditorFor creates?

Comment: You add a CSS rule. I'll add to the answer.